# Overlay on HTML5 Fullscreen Video

Tags: html, html5-video

I want to add overlay hotspots on a html5 video which will help me give info about that video. I was able to successfully add it on HTML5 Video's normal mode. But, when i change the video mode to fullscreen, it disappears. Want someone to help me please!!!.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a `<div>` containing the `<video>` and  hotspots, and request fullscreen on the containing `<div>`.

I implemented the fullscreen and (parts of the) `<video>` APIs in Firefox. This z-index hack isn't the specified behaviour, so it will stop working once we update our implementation to match the latest draft of the W3C fullscreen spec.

Comment: Spent half a day trying to figure out the z-index thing below in Firefox. This is a much better solution.

Comment: I don't think this is possible using the video control's fullscreen button which will set the video to fullscreen and can't be cancelled.

Comment: @junvar - maybe overlay the fullscreen button as well?

Comment: as a chrome extension, NOT web dev, is there any way to fullscreen the `<div>` containing the video, if the video was fullscreened using video fullscreen button: this emits no clickevent, so there's no way to exitFullScreen, then enterFullScreen of container `div`(requires user input!), one workaround I can think of is to replace the native controls of EVERY `video` with custom buttons, of which I can listen to the clickevent. W3C spec Solutions? : add onclick/keydown event to video fullscreen button.
OR make onfullscreenchange able to call requestFullscreen if it DID come from mouse/keyboard

Answer (score 18):

This can be solved with a trick. Have a look on this example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/show/

z-index: 2147483647;

You can also see the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/carmijoon/pZbkX/

```
z-index: 2147483647;
```

you need to add maximum value of z-index which is (z-index: 2147483647;) in to the overlay element. That trick will solve your issue.

Can you also share your file on jsfiddle?

Comment: Brilliant! Just brilliant! If I could upvote this answer by 100, I'd do so. I was despairing of getting an overlay on a fullscreen element till I found this answer. Thanks a million, Carmijoon!

Comment: It is working for chrome, but it seems does not work for firefox and IE

Comment: This does not work in mobile. Any idea how to get this to work on Android Chrome?

Comment: Downwote because all you euphoric upvoters, try the solution in Firefox

Comment: Here's the Firefox solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45798213/firefox-fullscreen-video-append-dom-elements

Comment: Down voting for it does not work in full screen.

Comment: doesn't seem to work any longer

Comment: does not work anymore