# Place content over *fullscreen* video using Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, video, web, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way to place regular html content (like a div/span/etc) over a *fullscreen* html5 video using a Chrome extension? Any way to do it over a flash video?

edit: 
I want to do this for an extension I am building that shows lyrics in sync with the song playing on video (when the user wants, that is).

Comment: You can do it using fullscreen API.Refer this https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overlay on HTML5 Fullscreen Video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234740/overlay-on-html5-fullscreen-video)

Comment: Asked and answered 2 years ago. Use the search, Luke! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234740/overlay-on-html5-fullscreen-video

Comment: I am building an extension. So the answers there might not apply. Edited to clarify.

Comment: The answers there apply. As an extension, you have the ability to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Make it as background.

```css
video#bgvid {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
z-index: -100;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
background: url(blablabla.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```