# Display div over fullscreen Vimeo player

Tags: javascript, html, overlay, fullscreen, vimeo

I have an embedded Vimeo player I'm calling and manipulating using the JavaScript API. I'm wondering if it's possible to display a div over top of the player while fullscreen? I've tried playing with the z-index values with no luck.

Comment: That doesn't work for you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234740/overlay-on-html5-fullscreen-video

Comment: It could work, but I'm not sure how to request fullscreen on the containing div as the fullscreen button is a part of the Vimeo player. Am I able to change the action of that button?