# how to pop-up modal while video is playing

Tags: javascript

I have a video on my main page and I can handle the pop-up modal on my screen, but the problem is when I click maximize option on the video and tried to play it, the modal pop-up now will fail to appear.

Here is my current pop-up call from my javascript:

```
var previousTime = 0;
var currentTime = 0;
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function (event) {                        
    previousTime = currentTime;
    currentTime = video.currentTime;

    curTime = Math.floor(currentTime)            

    if (curTime == '5') {
        console.log('pop the question now!')
        video.pause();

        $('#popQuestModal').modal('show');                               
    }

});
```

Is there something wrong or missing on my code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overlay on HTML5 Fullscreen Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234740/overlay-on-html5-fullscreen-video)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding setting the z-index of your modal window to 2147483647.

Comment: I tried to add it on my css but it still doesn't work.